# Is my iPhone bugged?

Tags: iphone, security, bug

Is there any way to determine if a non jail broken iPhone is bugged?, is it even possible to bug a non jail broken iPhone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are ways - though detection depends on what kind of bug we're talking about.

Is it possible to bug a non jail-broken iPhone: Yes.

Remember that a bug does not have to be in software - it could possibly also be in hardware. It also doesn't have to be in the actual phone, it could be placed in the cell network or in your providers systems.

In order to detect bugging, you could use equipment to scan for out of the ordinary radio emissions. You would also need to use a tool such as Wireshark to monitor network transmissions from the phone.

However a bug could elude such detection by being for example remotely activated or timed. Then you would need to employ your detection tools when the bug is actually active.

All in all it is very hard for an "ordinary Joe" to be certain that a phone is not bugged.

However, it is very unlikely that your phone is bugged if you really are an "ordinary Joe".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what do you think about a software like "Certo" that spouse to determine if there is a spyware on your iPhone. Worth to buy or a waste of money?

Comment: It's a completely different question. Also it is impossible for others to answer a question of whether something is worth it or not to you. That is highly subjective. However I can say that it is not worth it for me.